# typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any> debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, realm, decodable

Now I'm Facing this error

> Value of type '[UserOrderHistory]' has no member 'orderlist'

My JSON :

```
{
"OrderList": [
    {
        "orderId": 16976,
        "userId": 4905,
        "pickupdate": "2018-09-23",
    },
    {
        "orderId": 52,
        "userId": 4905,
        "pickupdate": "2018-08-07",
    },
],
"TotalOrder": 2
}
```

My Decodable Model Class:

```
    class UserOrderHistory: Object, Decodable {

      var orderlist: [OrderList]?
      var TotalO = RealmOptional<Int>()

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case orderlist = "OrderList"
        case TotalO = "TotalOrder"
     }
convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.orderlist = try container.decodeIfPresent(OrderList.self, forKey: .orderlist)
    self.TotalO.value = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .TotalO)
}

required init() {
    super.init()
}

required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
    super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
}

required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}
}


class OrderList: Object, Decodable{
var orderId = RealmOptional<Int>()
var userId = RealmOptional<Int>()
@objc dynamic var pickupdate: String? = nil

enum CatCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case orderId
    case userId
    case pickupdate
}

convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CatCodingKeys.self)
    self.orderId.value = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .orderId)
    self.userId.value = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .userId)

    self.pickupdate = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .pickupdate)

}

required init() {
    super.init()
}

required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
    super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
}

required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}
  }
```

Decode Server side Data to Realm Compatible:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
            let orders = try decoder.decode(Array<UserOrderHistory>.self, from: data)

                try? realm!.write {
                    realm?.add(orders.orderlist!)
                }

            }catch {
                 print(error)
            }
```

Where is the problem.

> 1. How I can solve this.
> 2. Is there any other and easy way to parse this type of json to using decodable.

Have mention the error on top.

Comment: I have changed my question, please take a look

Comment: @Balijinder did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

OrderList is an `array`. You need to change the variable `orderList` in `UserOrderHistory` class:

```
var orderlist: [OrderList]?
```

Keep this line as before only, remove `Array`:

`let orders = try decoder.decode([UserOrderHistory].self, from: data)`

to :

`let orders = try decoder.decode(UserOrderHistory.self, from: data)`

Comment: I have removed orderlist from realm?.add(orders). but facing this run time error typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0):

The following json object corresponds to only one instance of UserOrderHistory:

```
{
"OrderList": [
    {
        "orderId": 16976,
        "userId": 4905,
        "pickupdate": "2018-09-23",
    },
    {
        "orderId": 52,
        "userId": 4905,
        "pickupdate": "2018-08-07",
    },
],
"TotalOrder": 2
}
```

Hence using the following to decode will suffice:

```
let orders = try decoder.decode(UserOrderHistory.self, from: data)
```

You are trying to decode an array from an object the way I see it and that would fail.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try using `Array<UserOrderHistory>.self` instead of `UserOrderHistory.self`

In your `UserOrderHistory` class,

```
var orderlist: [OrderList]?
```

So the code should look like,

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
        let orders = try decoder.decode(Array<UserOrderHistory>.self, from: data)

            try? realm!.write {
                realm?.add(orders.orderlist!)
            }

        }catch {
             print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Value of type '[UserOrderHistory]' has no member 'orderlist'

Comment: ....This is error.... I have removed orderlist from realm?.add(orders). but facing this run time error typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))